# NodeWebkit with remote MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-webkit

I am working on simple nodewebkit project and I want to do this with a remote database.

What is the best and most secure way to connect remote to an sql server?

I already checked [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) and similar solutions but it doesn't look safe to place database connection credentials in a nodewebkit application.

So what should I do to keep my sql server safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use some sort of proxy for the DB requests. For  have a web server with public API serving the node-webkit clients. Use session and sign-in to make sure only allowed users consume this API, and make the web server make the request to the DB and returning the results.